# Floating point inaccuracy in R?

Tags: r, floating-accuracy

Does R have a known problem with uniroot and handling floating points?

```
>str(uniroot(function(x) x*(x^2-1) + .5, lower = -2, upper = 2,
+                  tol = 0.0001))

List of 4
$ root      : num -1.19
$ f.root    : num -2.55e-07
$ iter      : int 7
$ estim.prec: num 5e-05
> -1.19 * ( 1.19 ^ 2 - 1 ) + 0.5 
[1] 0.004841
```

Clearly the value of `f.root` is not equal to the value of the function calculated by hand.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/MagrittePipe.jpg

Comment: The function has only displayed 3 sig figs.

Comment: You're using the wrong hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value of root is shown to only 2 s.f., but it estimates the precision at 5e-5. That suggests it "knows" other digits in the answer that you are not looking at. Try to print out `root-1.19` and you will see what I mean.

In particular, `str` is intended as a *quick* way to view the structure of an R object, so it intentionally prints a limited number of digits: the default value of `digits.d` is 3 (see `?str`). Just printing the results (as in `uniroot(...)` or `u1 <- uniroot(...); u1` would have shown you more digits and perhaps have avoided the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your question please "accept" the answer. That, rather than a comment, tells the community "this answer solves this question".

Comment: I want to give a quick shout-out to @benbolker who edited the answer and made it more complete!